# ASP.NET Project Clone from Git Hub has broken database, but not from ZIP file from Google Drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, git, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET project that I am working on from a Udemy class.  I am also trying to familiarize myself with Git Hub so after an evening of working on the project, I will push it to the remote repository.  When I build and run the application on my machine at home it runs perfectly.  However, when I use my computer at work to clone the project from Git Hub, and run it, the project will build, however when I press a link that leads to a page that requires a database I get an error with my controller class '

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since
>   the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to
>   update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).

So I use the NuGet package manager to 'Update-Database' and receive the following error.

> Cannot find the object "dbo.Movies" because it does not exist or you
>   do not have permissions.

If I download the zip file from Git Hub I receive the same errors, however I put my project on google drive and downloaded it to my work computer and it works fine.  So I'm not sure what the problem would be, why my Movies database is not being built.  Perhaps I did something incorrectly while pushing the project from my computer to Git Hub?  I checked SQL Server object Explorer, my other database tables are there(dbo.Customers), just not dbo.Movies.  Here is the code to my DbContext class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    // add customers table to database
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    // add movies table to database
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {

    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

I did do a search and tried turning off the DB initializer, to see what would happen, but dbo.Movies still comes up missing. The files from my Google drive download and the Github clone seem to match up.  I'm just not sure what direction to head from here.  Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: "The files from my Google drive download and the Github clone seem to match up." I highly doubt it. Mount both at the same time and compare the schema.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by mounting both at the same time.  How do I go about doing that?

Comment: You have SQL Server Management Studio on your machine? Then [follow these directions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx).

Comment: I found that the App_Data folder and the .mdf and .ldf files within were missing from the cloned version of the project.  I copied those files from the original and inserted them in the cloned version and it worked.  I'm not sure why those files were ignored, something else to look in to, but this is solved for now.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check your .gitignore file. Database files normally aren't committed to source code control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question just to close it down.  Project was missing the .mdf file because, as mason said, 'Database files normally aren't committed to source code control.'  Something I'll keep in mind from now on.  I appreciate the help mason!